# How to change the time format in DateTime in RDLC?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have a RDLC Report which shows DateTime fields. It displays date time in Local System settings format(say en-US).

By default date string comes as follows,

```
10/08/2013 03:10.11 PM
```

I would like to just change the time format to 24 hours based on the input parameters dynamically  and i still want date to use the locale settings format.

example if(parameter.value = true) then it should display `10/08/2013 15:10.11` else

```
10/08/2013 03:10.11 PM
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you cheched how DateTime.ToString-works with format strings? Read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and see if it helps. If you call for example datetime.ToString("g") it is the globalization that affects how the date and time are formatted. Ofcourse you can explicitly tell how to format the datetime like

```
Dim d As New DateTime(2013, 10, 17, 14, 30, 0)
Dim s As String = d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
Dim s2 As String = d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

But remember that globalization will still affect the markers between date, month and year.

Comment: i want it as a datetime not as string

Comment: DateTime-object for both "10/08/2013 15:10.11" and "10/08/2013 03:10.11 PM" is exactly the same, so what you need is to format the datetime in certain way to be shown on the report. How to do the formatting in the report, I'm not sure. Have you bound the datetime to some label or something? Is there a possibility to give formatting string?

Comment: Yes, we are binding the field in the report. we can give the format string, but it would be static. I wanted to do it in the code behind and bind it there

Comment: Then you need to find an appropriate event before the databinding and set the formatting there according to the condition.